# Running meteor project on a newer version

Tags: meteor

Five months ago I created a project using meteor windows version 0.5.x, project works great on that version of meteor, but today, when I migrated to version 0.6.4.1 I had problems with the functionality of the project, three functions from model.js loss reference in client.js call (undefined  functions).

```
   Exception from Deps recompute: ReferenceError: displayName is not defined
   (but, this function is defined in model.js)
```

I noticed, from browser console that every function of the model lose reference in client.js.
I tried to run the project using the command

```
   meteor --release 0.5.x
```

but every try to run I get the error "Can't specify a release when running meteor from a checkout".
What would be the problem for undefined reference functions (in the release of newer version).

Comment: The `--release` argument only works for versions 0.6.0+.

Comment: That i didnt know thanks for info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor 0.6.x changed variable scoping across multiple files : each source file is encapsulated inside an anonymous function making its local var/function declarations visible only to the concerned file.
To enable exporting symbols and reference them in other files, you now have to use this syntax :

```
myVar=value;
// instead of
var myVar=value;

myFunc=function(){...};
// instead of
function myFunc(){...}
```

If you did something like

```
function displayName(){...}
```

in model.js, try replacing it with

```
displayName=function(){...};
```

I'm pretty sure it will do the trick.

Comment: After removing var keyword works like a charm, I spended hours for research and nothing. Thanks, you saved me!